# Adding ranges from different sheets into an EmbeddedChart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

Here is the situation. I have a Spreadsheet with two Sheets: 'Sheet1', and 'Sheet2'. They both have three columns of data, with 54 rows. I am trying to add ranges from both sheets in one EmbeddedChart. Here is my code snippet:

```js
function testplot(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var degrees = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1:A54'); //domain
  var range1 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B1:B54');  //header:'B1 SinA'
  var range2 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C1:C54');  //header:'C1 CosA'
  var range3 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange('B1:B54');  //header:'B2 SinA'
  var range4 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange('C1:C54');  //header:'C2 CosA'
  var chartsheet = s.getActiveSheet();
  var chartbuilder = chartsheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(degrees)
    .addRange(range1)
    .addRange(range2)
    .addRange(range3)
    .addRange(range4)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setPosition(5,2,0,0)
    .setOption('height',300)
    .setOption('width',900)
    .setOption('theme','maximized')
    .setOption('pointSize',2)
    .setOption('curveType','function')
  var chart = chartbuilder.build();
  chartsheet.insertChart(chart); 
  }
```

The resulting chart **only shows ranges from 'Sheet1'**:

[image]

This is what the chart looks like when all ranges are added manually:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Apps Script, and I've filed an issue to track it:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4026

The problem seems to be related to ranges that have the same bounds, so as a workaround you could offset your ranges so that they have different bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EricKoleda, good to know I wasn't missing something obvious! The workaround makes sense, but my actual Spreadsheet has quite a bit of sheets, and I am plotting all the ranges with the same bounds. Shifting all of them manually would take a while. Is it worth it to spend time on this, or it is reasonable to assume that the fix is gonna be quick?

Comment: Honestly, it may take a long time for this bug to be addressed, since it is a bit of an edge case. There are other potential workarounds, such as using formulas to merge all of the data into one sheet, and then build the chart from that.

Comment: I was actually heading toward a similar workaround, but thanks a lot for the honest answer! :) Just out of pure curiosity: the same task is doable manually using the chart GUI, what is the difference with the apps script implementation?

Comment: Also, why is this considered an edge case? Is it really that uncommon to plot ranges from different sheets, regardless of their bounds? Forgive me if I sound polemic, I am really just curious! :)

Comment: As is the case with software, some code is shared between the UI and the API and some code is distinct. In this case the Apps Script implementation has some faulty logic. 

I would also have thought the use case would be more common, but since you're the first person to stumble upon the bug in the two years since this feature was launched I'm guessing it must be a bit of an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be:

```
var range1 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B1:B54');
var range2 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C1:C54');
var range3 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange('B1:B55');
var range4 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange('C1:C55');
```

Extending past the range of values will not cause an issue to the results of the graph and allow this to work without having to move your data around.

Comment: That sounds like a simple and effective idea, thanks for the tip @nwill001! Going to test it now.